# Dynamically add text box

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Newbie at web..

This should be simple. I have text box the user should write City. I'd like the user to press on "Add City" and another text box will be shown (do this up to 3 times). can you give me headstart on how to implement this?

```
<section class="row-inner clearfix">
    <section class="form-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cities, new { @class = "autocomplete-init-no-img"})
        <label>Cities</label>
    </section>

    <section class="form-field">
        <a href="#">Add City</a>
    </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this client side via JS.  The examples I am showing you use JQuery.

Something like

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $("#section").append("<input type='text' name='City1'/>");
});
```

The problem with this is that you will end up dynamically having to deal with parameters.  If you know you only want to have 3, then that is fine.

If you wanted to use more of the built in controls, you could do something like.

```
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(...city1...)</div>
<div class="hidden">@Html.TextBoxFor(....city2....)</div>
```

Then for the JS, you could just find the first hidden one and unhide it.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $(".hidden").first().show();
});
```

You will also want to hide the "add city" button after all the cities that can be added have been added.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok I think I got it I'll try to implement and report back. BTW - if user will regret and will want to "delete" one of the cities, is that reversible in this solution?

Comment: The first solution might be a little bit more work if you want to "delete" a city.  As part of the append, you could add a delete button which looks at the element before and removes it from the DOM.  In the second solution, it would be as easy as hiding the element and clearing the content (which can all be done with Jquery).

Comment: mmm I'm trying to implement..have two issues...1-> can't get the second text box to appear below the first one, 2-> seems like class=hidden doesn't really hide it..

Comment: you will have to add CSS for "hidden" yourself.  display="none" is what you are looking for.  What do you mean you can't get the second text box to appear.. can you update the question with your new code?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript to create textbox with properties...

```
var input = document.createElement('input'); 
input.type = "text"; 
//...    
container.appendChild(input);
```

make a button and add an onClick function

```
<button id="myButton" onClick="javaScriptFunction();"> button Text </button>
```

in the function create the button (see code above) and add it to the HTML body ...